# Pymongo array query in "find" and "$in"

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to use Pymongo for my project, I want to view the data by using for loop, forEach, or Map to expand my array in my search query but I don't know how to do this.

my question:

How to for loop represent [postLike[0],postLike[1] in my search query?

Here is my code which can function normally but not in for loop.

```
@app.route("/user/addlikevideo", methods=["POST","GET"])
@jwt_required()
def add_like_video():
   if request.method =="GET":
        try:
            getTokenEmail = get_jwt()["sub"] //Get the email by Token

            existing_user = user_collection.find_one({"email": getTokenEmail}) //Find the user

            postLike = existing_user["likeVideos"] // the data like [4,25]

            // *** I want to use map or for loop something like that function to represent [postLike[0],postLike[1]....]
            thePostLike = post_collection.find({ "idCount": { "$in": [postLike[0],postLike[1]]}})
            listThePostLike = list(thePostLike)
            
            
            json_data = dumps(listThePostLike, indent = 4) 
            return json_data

        except:
            return "no liked post"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the objects which have an `idCount` equals to one of the `postLike` array elements, you can directly use the array in your query:

```py
@app.route("/user/addlikevideo", methods=["POST","GET"])
@jwt_required()
def add_like_video():
   if request.method =="GET":
        try:
            getTokenEmail = get_jwt()["sub"] //Get the email by Token

            existing_user = user_collection.find_one({"email": getTokenEmail}) //Find the user

            postLike = existing_user["likeVideos"] // the data like [4,25]
            thePostLike = post_collection.find({ "idCount": { "$in": postLike}})
            listThePostLike = list(thePostLike)
            
            
            json_data = dumps(listThePostLike, indent = 4) 
            return json_data

        except:
            return "no liked post"
```

And if you want to filter the elements:

```py
thePostLike = post_collection.find({ "idCount": { "$in": [ele for ele in postLike if (ele > 10)]}}) # you can use any filter
```